# Roku SDK 2.0 Video Node headers are being stripped

Tags: roku

I am currently running into an issue where my headers are being stripped when requesting playback of the video node.  The server requires these headers to be able to playback the content.

```
device=CreateObject("roDeviceInfo")
hvideo = CreateObject("roHttpAgent")
hvideoheaders = {
"Device": device.GetDeviceUniqueId(),
"DeviceProf": device.GetModelDisplayName()+"("+device.GetModel()+";"+device.GetVersion()+";Roku;roku)",
"Version": "C4.9.9_S0",
"x-roku-reserved-dev-id": "",
}
hvideo.SetHeaders(hvideoheaders)

'set videoContent Parameters

videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
videoContent.url = streamUrl
videoContent.Title = m.top.item.Title
videoContent.StreamFormat = "hls"
videoContent.SubtitleConfig = subtitle_config
videoContent.HttpSendClientCertificates = true


'Set Video
m.video = m.top.findNode("musicvideos")
m.video.SetConnectionTimeout(30)
'm.video.notificationInterval = 30
m.video.observeField("state", "stateChanged")
m.video.observeField("streamInfo", "streamInfoChanged")
m.video.observeField("streamingSegment", "streamingSegmentChanged") 
m.video.content = videoContent
m.video.setHttpAgent(hvideo)
m.video.control = "play"
```

The only header that comes across is x-roku-reserved-dev-id when using a differnt HTTP Agent.

If i use the video nodes content metadata for the headers, all the headers are present EXCEPT x-roku-reserved-dev-id which fails the webserver access rules. This is how I have tried to set these:

```
headers = []
headers.push("x-roku-reserved-dev-id:")
headers.push("Device:" + device.GetDeviceUniqueId())
headers.push("DeviceProf:" + device.GetModelDisplayName()+"("+device.GetModel()+";"+device.GetVersion()+";Roku;roku)")
headers.push("Version:C4.9.9_S0")

videoContent.HttpHeaders = headers
```

I have tried setting just the content nodes without the x-roku-reserved-dev-id and the HTTPAgent with the x-roku-reserved-dev-id however it is the same result...

Any thoughts?

Comment: suggest closing since it's a firmware issue and no longer relevant to future Roku devs

Answer (score 0):

You should add headers to roUrlTransfer object:

```
request = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
request.SetRequest("POST")
request.AddHeader(headerName1, headerValue1)
request.AddHeader(headerName2, headerValue2)
request.AddHeader(headerName3, headerValue3)
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually ended up being a firmware issue with Roku. It has since been fixed in firmware v7.7 b 4061+

Answer (score 0):

This actually ended up being a firmware issue with Roku. ROKU has since released the fixed firmware v7.7 b 4061+